# How to use system environment variables in VS 2008 Post-Build events?

Tags: visual-studio, build-process

How do I use system environment variables in my project post-build events without having to write and execute an external batch file?  I thought that it would be as easy as creating a new environment variable named `LHDLLDEPLOY` and writing the following in my post-build event textbox:

```
copy $(TargetPath) %LHDLLDEPLOY%\$(TargetFileName) /Y
copy $(TargetName).pdb %LHDLLDEPLOY%\$(TargetName).pdb /Y
```

...but alas, no.  The build output shows that it wrote the files to the "`%LHDLLDEPLOY%`" folder (as "`1 file(s) copied`" twice), but the files are not in the equated path and there is not a new folder called "`LHDLLDEPLOY`"

Where did they actually go, and how do I do this correctly?

(UPDATE: **Xavier** nailed it.  Also, his variable format of `$(LHDLLDEPLOY)` worked after I rebooted the machine to refresh the environment variables.)

(UPDATE 2: Turns out that I did not have to reboot my machine.  I just needed to make sure that I a) closed the Environment Variables list window, and b) closed/relaunched Visual Studio.)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Did you try $(LHDLLDEPLOY) instead of %LHDLLDEPLOY%?

Answer (score 0):

Not all the variables defined in "Visual Studio command prompt" are accessible in post-build script. Here is the script solving this problem:

```
call "$(DevEnvDir)..\..\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat"
"%VCINSTALLDIR%Tools\MSVC\%VCToolsVersion%\bin\Hostx64\x64\editbin.exe" /NOLOGO /STACK:2097152 "$(TargetPath)"
```